Solution of a linear homogeneous PDE using the method of Separation of Variables
in the following PDE, I got stuck on an integral while solving it, I was wondering if anyone could give me a hint on how to calculate this integral. I appreciate any help you can provide.
Here's what I've done so far:
$$
\begin{gather}
 \displaystyle u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}\quad:\;\;0<x<1,\quad t>0 \\ \\
\text{Boundary Conditions}:
\begin{cases}
 \displaystyle u(0,t)=0 \\ \\ 
 \displaystyle u(1,t)=0
\end{cases} \quad\quad \large : t\ge 0
\\ \\
\text{Initial Conditions}:
\begin{cases}
 \displaystyle u(x,0)=f(x)=x(1-x) \\ \\ 
 \displaystyle u_{t}(x,0)=g(x)=x-\tan \frac{\pi x}{4}
\end{cases} \quad\quad \large :0\le x \le 1 \\ \\
\text{Separation of Variables}:
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)\ne 0 \\ \\
\displaystyle u_{tt}=XT'' \\ \\
\displaystyle u_{xx}=X''T
\end{cases} \\ \\
\text{by substituting these into our original PDE we get:} \\ \\
 \displaystyle 
XT''=c^2X''T \xrightarrow{\div XT} \frac{T''}{T}=c^2 \frac{X''}{X}=\underbrace{\lambda}_{\text{constant of separation}} \\ \\
\longrightarrow
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle  X''-\frac{\lambda}{c^2}X=0 \\ \\ \\
\displaystyle  T''-\lambda T=0
\end{cases} \quad\text{(Sturm-Liouville Problem)}
\end{gather}
$$
by observing our boundary and initial conditions it is pretty self-explanatory that to solve the ODE corresponding $ T(t)$ we have to solve the ODE corresponding $ X(x)$ first:
$$
\begin{gather}
 \text{BC's}:
\begin{cases}
 \displaystyle
X(0)=0 \\ \\
X(1)=0 
\end{cases}
\quad \quad 
 \text{IC's}:
\begin{cases}
 \displaystyle T(0)=\frac{f(x)}{X(x)} \\ \\
 \displaystyle T'(0)=\frac{g(x)}{X(x)} 
\end{cases}
\end{gather}
$$
now by solving the Sturm-Liouville problem corresponding to $ X(x)$ we see that in this particular case the nontrivial solutions of this Sturm-Liouville problem occur only for negative values of $\lambda$:
$$
\begin{gather}
 \displaystyle \xrightarrow{\text{if}\,\, \lambda<0 ,\, \lambda= -\alpha^2} X''+\frac{\alpha^2}{c^2}X=0 \quad\quad ( \alpha > 0,\alpha \ne 0 )
\end{gather}
$$
which will obtain the following solution for $ X(x)$:
$$
\begin{gather}
 \displaystyle X(x)=c_{1}\cos\left( \frac{\alpha x}{c} \right)+c_{2}\sin\left( \frac{\alpha x}{c} \right) \\ \\
\large \displaystyle 
\xrightarrow{\text{using BC's}} 
\begin{cases} 
\displaystyle \alpha=n\pi c \\  \\
\displaystyle  X(x)=c_{2}\sin (n\pi x)
\end{cases}
\end{gather}
$$
now we can solve for $ T(t)$:
$$
\begin{gather}
 \displaystyle T''+\alpha^2 T=0 \\ \\ 
\longrightarrow  \displaystyle T(t)=c_{3}\cos (n\pi ct)+c_{4}\sin(n\pi ct)
\end{gather}
$$
now that we solved for $ X(x)$ and $ T(t)$ we can use the linear combination to
find a solution for the PDE (for $n$ different values of $ \lambda$ we can have $n$ different solutions):
$$
\begin{gather}
 \displaystyle u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \eta_n X_{n}T_{n} \\ \\
 \displaystyle u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg[\underbrace{\eta_{n}c_{2n}c_{3n}}_{p_{n}}\cos(n\pi ct)+\underbrace{\eta_{n}c_{2n}c_{4n}}_{q_{n}}\sin(n\pi ct)\bigg]\sin(n\pi x) \\ \\
 \displaystyle u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg[p_{n}\cos(n\pi ct)+q_{n}\sin(n\pi ct)\bigg]\sin(n\pi x) \\ \\
\large \displaystyle 
\xrightarrow{IC's}
\begin{cases}
 \displaystyle u(x,0)=f(x)\rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p_{n}\sin (n\pi x)=f(x)\approx \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}\sin(n\pi x) \\ \\
\large \displaystyle p_{n}=b_{n}=2\int_{0}^{1}x(1-x)\sin(n\pi x)dx=4\left[ \frac{1-(-1)^n}{{n\pi}^3} \right] \\  \\
\large \displaystyle
u_{t}(x,0)=g(x) \rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n\pi c)q_{n}\sin (n\pi x)=g(x)\approx \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}'\sin(n\pi x)
\end{cases} \\ \\
 \displaystyle
q_{n}=\frac{b_{n}'}{n\pi c}=\frac{2}{n\pi c}\int_{0}^{1}\left( x-\tan \left( \frac{\pi x}{4} \right)\sin(n\pi x)dx \right) \\ \\
 \displaystyle
=\frac{2}{n\pi c}\left[ \underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}x\sin(n\pi x)dx}_{\displaystyle I_1}-\underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}\sin(n\pi x)\tan\left( \frac{\pi x}{4} \right)dx}_{\displaystyle I_2=?} \right]
\end{gather}
$$
the first part of this integral is pretty straightforward forward but I have no clue as to how to solve the second part

why the text is so large?

Something wrong with the boundary condition: $u(\pi,t)=0$ or $u(1,t)=0$?

@gpmath I found this problem in Myint U's PDE book and the BC's are exactly as I posted (I rechecked it in the book)

@illestboi But the $x$-range is $0<x<1$: IC's and BC's are only consistent with $u(1,t)=0$.
$b_n$ also is wrong: Must be $b_n \sim \frac{1}{n^3}$.

@gpmath in that case the problem is wrong altogether am I right? also I calculated $b_n$ again and got the same result as before can you please point out where I got it wrong?

@illestboi $\int_0^1 x(1-x) \sin(n x)=\frac{2-2\cos(n)-n\sin(n)}{n^3}$
but
$\int_0^1 x(1-x) \sin(n \color{red}{\pi} x)=2\frac{1-(-1)^n}{(n\color{red}{\pi})^3}$

Correct is
$$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg[p_n \cos(n\pi c t)+q_n \sin(n\pi c t)\bigg]\cdot \sin(n \color{red}{\pi} x)$$
otherwise the PDE isn't satisfied.

@gpmath Thanks I get it now and I edited the Boundary condition in my problem but the problem of calculating the last integral for finding coefficient $q_n$ still insists, I did a little bit of cheating and solved the integral in Mathematica the result is too complicated, here's the result link

@illestboi See MATLAB script MSE_Q5004780
